# Google Maps Polygon Fill Color Disappearing with improper geometry

Tags: android, google-maps

I am having an issue with keeping the polygon fill color present in the polygon on the Google Maps Android platform. When the polygon path overlaps itself the fill color disappears. I am using the same method for highlighting my path on iOS and it does not have this behavior. Please see these images to note how the the fill color disappears when there is an overlap in the polygon path.

Here is the correct color fill before overlap:

[image: Before overlap]

The color disappears when there are polygon path points that are within the same polygon:

[image: After overlap]

The behavior is not the same on iOS. The polygon keeps its fill on iOS. This is an excerpt from the Google Maps documentation:

```
Fill color in ARGB format, the same format 
used by Color. The default value is 
transparent (0x00000000). If the polygon 
geometry is not specified correctly (see 
above for Outline and Holes), then no fill 
will be drawn.
```

Here is the code that I am using. Basically I have a path with a width X and that path at width X is highlighted:

As the location changes I take the current location and calculate a left and right point for example:

```
LatLng leftPoint = 
SphericalUtil.computeOffset(presentLoc, 
widthInFeet * 0.3048, heading - 90);
```

Next I take the right side and reverse the array and add it to the left to make the polygon path. I then pass in that array of points into the polygon for update as the location changes.

```
polygon.setPoints(polyPoints);
polygon.setFillColor(YELLOW);
polygon.setStrokeWidth(1);
```

How does one make the image above retain its fill color when there is the inevitable overlap when for example there is a sharp turn etc?

I used this com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil.simplify from below to do a Douglas-Peucker simplification, however this does not help with sharp turns that overlap or pass back over the path. I am tempted to use multiple smaller polygons instead of one large polygon, but I don't want to waste the system resources especially when the app will have fairly large paths.

Comment: Sounds like a bug; I wonder if using the com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil.simplify when polygon is complex would be a possible workaround, which in theory would eliminate the interior triangle thing in your example, if that is suitable for you.

Comment: `if the polygon geometry is not specified correctly` hints for, that this polygon should not have a hole in the first place, or at least have these verticles punched out.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I'd at least demonstrate what simplification can accomplish and let you decide if it is desirable.  Frankly, I have not seen a lot of examples of how their algorithm performs.

The problem turns into what the tolerance parameter needs to be - a potentially difficult one for a general case.

The code is straight forward - two polygons are created, one a result of simplification.  This also demonstrates the bug where the clear polygon is not being filled.

```
    List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    points.add(new LatLng(39.182937,-76.823560));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.180741,-76.821758));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.190454, -76.810985));
    points.add(new LatLng( 39.190221, -76.812530));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.186961, -76.808239));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.188724,-76.806264));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.192882, -76.811328));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.182937, -76.823560));

    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
            .addAll(points);
    // Get back the mutable Polygon
    Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
    polygon.setFillColor(Color.YELLOW);


    points = new ArrayList<>();
    points.add(new LatLng(39.182937,-76.834560));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.180741,-76.832758));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.190454, -76.821985));
    points.add(new LatLng( 39.190221, -76.823530));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.186961, -76.819239));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.188724,-76.817264));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.192882, -76.822328));
    points.add(new LatLng(39.182937, -76.834560));
    points = PolyUtil.simplify(points, 200.0);

    rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
            .addAll(points);
    // Get back the mutable Polygon
    polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
    polygon.setFillColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

And finally the results - so clearly some fidelity is sacrificed in the simplification where one vertex of the inner triangle won out in the algorithm - but interesting none the less:

[image]

Note in this example the tolerance threshold is about 120 meters - the point at which it has an effect.

I do agree with @MartinZeitler that the solution for you most likely will be to remove the interior points.

Comment: Thanks for the visual example. I used the simplify method you have suggested, however, this app is used for precise highlighting with external GPS devices with the goal of being within a couple meters. I can get the simplify to work, at high tolerance, however that doesn't work well in this situation. I've been using the single polygon approach for a while on iOS with Google Maps, but it doesn't behave the same way as the android API. I think I am going to attempt to fill the area with an SVG or similar. Thanks again for the example.

Answer (score 0):

In onMapReady to call method- onpostExe();

```
private void onpostExe() {
        if (points != null && points.size() > 0) {
            PolylineOptions lineOptions;
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(8);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            lineOptions.geodesic(true);
 mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
}
```

on overlap is possible but, when use width size to spacify the difference on solve overlap problem